# How to load data from Cassandra to Druid

Tags: cassandra, druid

I am newbie to Druid. I am able to ingest data to Druid from S3, Kafka. Now, I want to load data from Cassandra hosted over AWS private subnet.

Is it even possible? If yes, please share some resources.

Answer (score 0):

No. There doesn't seem to be any support for direct ingest from Cassandra. But you could [setup Cassandra CDC to kafka](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2019/12/cassandra-source-connector-part-1.html) and use kafka ingestion.